# How to access a class from within another class.

Tags: c#, arrays

Need assistance accessing the account class. When I run the program it prompts with the ATM class's WriteLine("Welcome/Enter Account/Exit");. After I enter a number however, the command window just closes. I'm not sure what to do here. I should also mention this is my first program with C Sharp. Also, I'm not sure why people are down-voting my question, as I'm new to the site.

Account Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Account //Within the Account class, we have balance, withdraw,and deposit
    {

        ////An account array to create 3 seperate accounts each with a default balance of $100.00. 
        //int[] myAccount = new int[3];
        Account[] account = new Account[3];


        public double balance;

        public void deposit(double n)
        {
            balance += n;
        }
        public void withdraw(double n)
        {
            balance -= n;
        }
        public void calcInterest(double n)
        {
            //Here is where we calculate the interest!
        }

        public void menu()
        {
            {
                {

                    int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    var currAccount = account[input]; // Not sure what this code is for. 


                    if (account[input] == null)
                    {
                        account[input] = new Account();
                        account[input].balance = 100; //Set initial balance to $100
                    }

                    if (input != 4)
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("1) Deposit");
                        Console.WriteLine("2) Withdraw");
                        Console.WriteLine("3) Get Balance");
                        Console.WriteLine("4) Exit");
                        if(input == 1)
                            {
                            Console.WriteLine("How much would you like to deposit today?");
                            int moneyIn = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                            account[input].deposit(moneyIn); //access the deposit method and increase balance by the amount entered by user.
                            Console.WriteLine("Here is your current balance:" + account[input].balance);
                        }

                            if(input == 2)
                            {

                            Console.WriteLine("How much would you like to withdraw today?");
                            int moneyOut = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                            account[input].withdraw(moneyOut); //Access the withdraw method and decrease balance by the amount entered by user.
                            Console.WriteLine("Here is your current balance:" + account[input].balance);
                        }

                        if (input == 3)
                            {

                            Console.WriteLine("Here is your current balance:"+account[input].balance);
                            //return account[input].balance;
                        }

                        if (input == 4)
                        {
                            //I want to exit the application here. 
                        }                  
                     }
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ATM Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Atm //With the atm class we will have the atm menu
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Welcome!");
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your account number (1-3 or '4' to exit.");
            int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            {



                if (input >= 1 && input <= 3)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You have entered " + input);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    //ConsoleApplication3.Account[input]; // How do I access the account here? 
                }
                else if (input == 4)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Goodbye.");
                    //Exit Application
                }
              }
           }
        }
    }
```

Program Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
      //Not really sure what this is for at the moment, or if it is even needed. 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, don't put the Console.WriteLine and Console.ReadLine logics inside Account class. That is, user interaction code should have their own place, perhaps inside Atm class, but in their own method.

Inside the Atm class, create a references for the Accounts, like this

```
Accounts[] accounts = new Accounts[3]
```

Reduce the repetition for main menu input. If input is between 1 & 3, just call

```
Console.WriteLine("You have selected account "+input);
```

So the input processing will become :

```
int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
{
   if (input >=1 && input <= 3)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("You have entered "+input);
      Console.ReadLine();
      //Access Account 
   }                    
   else if (input == 4)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Goodbye.");
      //Exit Application
   }
}
```

Then access the associated account like this

```
if (accounts[input]==null)
{
   accounts[input] = new Account();
}
currAccount = accounts[input];
//either call the account interaction menu or write it here
```

Also, the withdraw method need to ensure there's enough balance (or if overdraft is allowed, the max overdraft amount).

Comment: No, you don't add them to readlines. I'll edit my comment to show how

Comment: Accounts[] accounts = new Accounts[3] Also where does this go? right now I'm getting an error with mine.

Comment: Please read the the [C# Programming Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67ef8sbd.aspx) first before asking further.

Comment: Okay, fixed that part. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to access an Account object, first instantiate it and give it a name, here the object is called theAcc.

```
Account theAcc = new Account();
```

If you'd like to access that object's properties, for example, the balance, you could do something like:

```
Console.Writeline("The account's balance is: " + theAcc.Balance);
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding still.